# Is there a way to prevent MS/VS mixing tabs and spaces?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, code-formatting

Whenever I have to open a *.Designer.cs file, I get a bar across the top that says, "You have mixed tabs and spaces. Fix this?" with the following buttons "Tabify" "Untabify" and "Don't show again"

I'm just as unnerved as the next guy about mixed tabs and spaces, so I don't want to mash "Don't show again."

But why is MS/VS causing this mismatch in the first place? I certainly don't touch this file - it is generated by a "tool," so to speak.

Is this something I just have to "live with" or...???

Comment: Can you show what the code looks like ? at least the portion that the compiler is complaining about

Comment: It doesn't highlight any particular line; it just shows that banner across the top.

Comment: can you do a screen shot then..?

Comment: I fixed/tabified it, so it's not a problem now/nothing to show.

Comment: ok.. sounds good.. has this been resolved then..?

Comment: No, it hasn't been resolved - it happens once in a while; I never know when, or why, it happens.

Comment: It happened again just now; posted a scream shot at: http://warbler.posterous.com/to-tabify-or-not-to-tabify#